# Combinations question elementory

Tags: combinations

> The value of
>   $$\binom{10}{0}^{2}-\binom{10}{1}^{2}+\binom{10}{2}^{2}......-\binom{10}{9}^{2}+\binom{10}{10}^{2}$$
>   is:
>
> A)$\binom{10}{5}$
>
> A)$\binom{10}{5}^{2}$
>
> c)$-\binom{10}{5}$
>
> d) $10!$

Comment: It's the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{10}\binom{10}n x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{10}(-1)^n\binom{10}n x^n\right)$.

Comment: If this were of any real concern, it would not be all that difficult to evaluate the sum and compare the result to the multiple choice of answers.  When a problem is quoted so precisely without any indication that its meaning has been digested, Readers may ask the OP to add context to the Question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the it's the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in  $$(x+1)^{10}(1-x)^{10}=(1-x^2)^{10}$$ which is $$\binom{10}5(-1)^5$$